# Sequelize Syntax Error (N\')

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js, string-interpolation

I'm trying a like query in name & surname columns with a dynamic input, using ES6 string interpolation.

This is my code:

```
User.findAll({  
    where: {
        [Op.or] : [
            {   
                nombre: {
                    [Op.iLike] : `%${name}%`
                }
            },
            {
                apellido: {
                    [Op.iLike] : `%${name}%`
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    attributes:userAttr,
})
```

Sequelize adds automatically N\' at beginning in each dynamic variable, and throws the following SQL statement:

```
 'SELECT [id] AS [id], [mail] AS [email], [nombre] AS [name], [apellido] AS [surname], [nro_celular] AS [cellphone], [tipo] AS [type], [id_usuario_estado_actual] AS [userCurrentStatusID], [push_token] AS [pushToken], [push_user_id] AS [pushUserID], [documento] AS [document], [tipo_documento] AS [documentType], [fecha_creacion] AS [creationDate], [id_ciudad] AS [cityID], [id_empresa] AS [companyID], [default_payment] AS [paymentDefault] FROM [dbo].[usuario] AS [user] WHERE ([user].[nombre] ILIKE N\'%Axel Candia%\' OR [user].[apellido] ILIKE N\'%Axel Candia%\');'
```

Which throws the following error

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: Incorrect syntax near 'ILIKE'.`

I've tried the following suggestions, unsuccessfully:

1. `[Op.iLike] : '%'+name+'%'`
2. `$iLike : '%'+name+'%'`
3. `[Op.iLike] : ['%'+name+'%'`]

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED 6/28/2018 11:03 AM**

The error wasn't focused in N\' added by Sequelize,

`[Op.iLike]` it's only for PG (Postgres) Database, not mine (SQL Server).

Instead, `[Op.like]` works as charm! However, I should code a solution for insensitive case in dynamic variables.